# Azure Application Error when upgraded from .NET 7 to .NET 8

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-7.0, .net-8.0

I recently updated my .NET 7 app to .NET 8 and deployed it to my web app (Linux). After deployment I am getting this error:

> :( Application Error
>
> If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

I got the logs from the Log stream and here was the issue.

> 2023-11-16T12:06:46.592Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container octufit-api-dev-1_0_36440c88 for site octufit-api-dev-1
>
> 2023-11-16T12:06:48.667Z ERROR - Container octufit-api-dev-1_0_36440c88 for site octufit-api-dev-1 has exited, failing site start
>
> 2023-11-16T12:06:48.754Z ERROR - Container octufit-api-dev-1_0_36440c88 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
>
> 2023-11-16T12:06:48.785Z INFO  - Stopping site octufit-api-dev-1 because it failed during

I have tried to add PORT 8080 and WEBSITES_PORT 8080 in application settings but nothing is working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you moved to fast to .NET 8. They just published an article on  November 14, 2023 - "[.NET 8 GA available on App Service](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2023/11/14/dotnet8-ga.html)". They say that:

```
expecting to be fully done by the end of the week
```

so you better wait for them (at least November 19, 2023) to fully configure/setup the environments.

Answer (score 1):

The author said he did this, and it didn't work, but this did work for us. Just posting this here for posterity. We were at a loss as to why our new container on .NET 8 didn't work in our app service. It was the port change that was the issue. Per [the docs](https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dotnet/aspnet/about)

Note: ASP.NET Core apps (in official images) listen to port 8080 by default, starting with .NET 8.

You need to set the WEBSITES_PORT appsetting to 8080 in your App Service. This will make your app service run `docker run -d --expose=8080` when running your image as a container and have your app service route requests to it.

Here's the az command for reference if you want to use it:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --settings WEBSITES_PORT=8080
```